# Create debug location for function calls in LLVM function pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I have created an optimization (function) pass that instruments specific instructions and creates function calls before target instructions. It works fine, but I cannot enable debug symbols (*-g*) due to not having a debug location for my custom function calls.

```
i8*  %381 = call i8* @my_function(i64* %375)
inlinable function call in a function with debug info must have a !dbg location
```

How can I create a debug location for a custom function call (e.g., *my_function*) in an LLVM optimization pass?

Comment: Were you able to fix this by adding debug location, or did you make the function non-inlinable?

Answer (score 2):

That limitation only applies to inlinable function calls. If your function isn't inlinable, you can mark it as such, `my_function->addAttribute(AttributeList::FunctionIndex, Attribute::NoInline);` and avoid the problem.